# How to display multiple tables dynamically using one button click using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Hi i want to display multiple table and the table data will be dynamically brought by consuming json data on single button click using ajax & javascript,jquery . For single table i can generate table using  this below procedure.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,
    data: "Id=" + clO + "&Location=" + clOp +"",

    success: function (resp) {          
        var Location = resp;
        var tr;          
        for (var i = 0; i < Location.length; i++) {

            tr = tr + "<td style='height:20px' align='left'>" + Location[i].name + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "<td style='height:20px' align='right'>" + Location[i].QTY + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "<td style='height:20px' align='right'>" + Location[i].AMT + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "</tr>";

        };
        document.getElementById('p_w').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('Wise').innerHTML = "<table id='rt1' >" + "<thead ><tr><th style='height:20px'>Name</th>" + "<th style='height:20px'>Qty</th>" + "<th style='height:20px'>Amnt</th>"+ "</tr></thead>"
            + tr +
            "<tr><td style='height:20px'></td></tr>" +
            "</table>";
        document.getElementById('Wise').childNodes[0].nodeValue = null;

    },
    error: function (e) {
        SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
        window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Please Enable your Internet 
        SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();

    }
});
```

But for generating the multiple tables using on single click using ajax how can we generate  and i want to generate multiple tables in below format

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p> Table 1</p>
<table style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p> Table 2</p>
<table style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Marks</th> 
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Science</td>
    <td>70</td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Computers</td>
    <td>80</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Art</td>
    <td>70</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Table 3</p>
<table style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <th>Laptop</th>
    <th>Price</th> 
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dell</td>
    <td>$350</td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lenovo</td>
    <td>$450</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Asus</td>
    <td>$200</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: did you try it ?

Comment: @ Faisal Mehmood Awan  yeah using ajax with in another ajax but it is not working out

Comment: Do you want to make multiple calls and add the html ? At first set document.getElementById('Wise').innerHTML = ''; Then inside each ajax call document.getElementById('Wise').innerHTML += '<p>Table X</p><table> you html goes here </table>'.  etc so it will get added up.

Comment: @gijjo can we create 3 tables in single ajax or button click

Comment: Mentioned ajax is returning 'Location' with fields name, QTY, AMT.  So from where will you get student and mark list that need to be filled in next two tables? If It comes along with this ajax response, please expain the json structure.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* Sample response expected as Ajax  */
var data = {
  Student: [{
    name: 'abc',
    age: '20'
  }, {
    name: 'xyz',
    age: '30'
  }],
  MarkList: [{
    subject: 'English',
    mark: '50'
  }, {
    subject: 'Arabic',
    mark: '75'
  }],
  Products: [{
    company: "Dell",
    Amount: '50'
  }, {
    company: "HP",
    Amount: '100'
  }]
};

/* Called on Ajax success  */
fnAjaxSuccess(data);

function fnAjaxSuccess(data) {
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = '';
  FillStudentList(data.Student, 1);
  FillMarkList(data.MarkList, 2)
  FillProductList(data.Products, 3);
}

/* Creating 1st table  */
function FillStudentList(Student, tableIndex) {
  var html = "<p> Table " + tableIndex + "</p><table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < Student.length; i++) {
    html += "<tr><td>" + Student[i].name + "</td><td>" + Student[i].age + "</td></tr>"
  }
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += (html + "</table>");
}

/* Creating 2nd table  */
function FillMarkList(MarkList, tableIndex) {
  var html = "<p> Table " + tableIndex + "</p><table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < MarkList.length; i++) {
    html += "<tr><td>" + MarkList[i].subject + "</td><td>" + MarkList[i].mark + "</td></tr>"
  }
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += (html + "</table>");
}

/* Creating 3rd table  */
function FillProductList(Products, tableIndex) {
  var html = "<p> Table " + tableIndex + "</p><table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < Products.length; i++) {
    html += "<tr><td>" + Products[i].company + "</td><td>" + Products[i].Amount + "</td></tr>"
  }
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += (html + "</table>");
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'></div>
```

Here it's assumed that, Your ajax response will have enough data for filling 3 tables.

You can write this as

```
$(document).on('click', '#id-of-button', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,
        data: "Id=" + clO + "&Location=" + clOp +"",

        success: function (resp) {
            fnAjaxSuccess(resp);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
            window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Please Enable your Internet 
            SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
        }
    });
});
```